# Red Black Tree in Linux

Tags: c, pointers, linux-kernel, red-black-tree

I am working on a Linux kernel project that involves using the rb_tree defined in rbtree.h. Here is the structure that I am storing in the tree:

```
struct source_store{
    sector_t source;
    sector_t cache;
    struct rb_node * node;
}
```

In order to retrieve objects from the tree, I do the following:

```
struct rb_node * parent = root->rb_node;
struct source_store * store = rb_entry(parent, struct source_store, node);
```

However, when compiling, I get this error:

```
warning: initialization from incompatible pointer type
```

Also, the number that I store in the source and cache fields are different when I retrieve the struts from the tree. For example, I would store the number 512 in the source field, and when I retrieve the struct later on, it would be some ridiculously large number like 16810075660910329857. From what I understand, sector_t is a long long unsigned integer. Why would the number stored change? Why are the pointer types incompatible?

Comment: How can you pass `struct source_store` as the 2nd param - it's a data type not a variable. Also, what's the prototype of `rb_entry`?

Comment: According to this tutorial: http://lwn.net/Articles/184495/ , the type has to be passed in. The prototype is: rb_entry(pointer, type, member); where member is the name of the node in the containing structure. rb_entry is just a wrapper for container_of().

Comment: That's because `rb_entry` is a macro and not a function. This is why you needed to provide this info in the question - the definition of rb_entry.

Comment: @user93353 The Linux Kernel is full of these kind of macros.  It seems to me that making the assumption that the readers understand the basic APIs of the Linux Kernel when the linux-kernel tag is present is a reasonable assumption.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should define your `struct source_store` as:

```
struct source_store{
    sector_t source;
    sector_t cache;
    struct rb_node node; // not a pointer to node
}
```

That is because `rb_entry` is defined as

```
#define rb_entry(ptr, type, member) container_of(ptr, type, member)
```

And it is just some simple offset calculation

```
#define container_of(ptr, type, member) ({             /
         const typeof( ((type *)0)->member ) *__mptr = (ptr);  /   <--error happens here
         (type *)( (char *)__mptr - offsetof(type,member) );})
```

The type of `__mptr` is `struct rb_node**` and the type of your `ptr` is `struct rb_node*`. So there is a warning of incompatible pointer type.